# Flutter: How to call a method of an instance from another class

Tags: android, ios, dart, cross-platform, flutter

I am trying to create an application that manages Views with Tab.
The navigation bar and the tab bar are displayed in the application, and the content of the content to be displayed is managed by List.

This is the class that manages the content of Tab.

```
class TabItem {
  TabItem({
    Widget view,
    Widget icon,
    Widget activeIcon,
    String title,
    TickerProvider vsync,
  })  : _view = view,
        _title = title,
        item = BottomNavigationBarItem(
          icon: icon,
          // activeIcon: activeIcon,
          title: Text(title),
        ),
        controller = AnimationController(
          duration: kThemeAnimationDuration,
          vsync: vsync,
        ) {
    _animation = CurvedAnimation(
      parent: controller,
      curve: const Interval(0.5, 1.0, curve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn),
    );
  }

  final Widget _view;
  final String _title;
  final BottomNavigationBarItem item;
  final AnimationController controller;
  CurvedAnimation _animation;

  FadeTransition transition(
      BottomNavigationBarType type, BuildContext context) {
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  //transition animation setting method
  ~~~~~~~~~~~~
  }
}
```

This is main.dart
Depending on the action of the user, the content in the List is displayed.

```
void main() {
  SystemChrome
      .setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]).then((_) {
    runApp(MyApp());
  });
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: RootTabView(), 
    );
  }
}

class RootTabView extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _RootTabViewState createState() => _RootTabViewState();
}

class _RootTabViewState extends State<RootTabView>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  int _currentIndex = 0;
  BottomNavigationBarType _type = BottomNavigationBarType.fixed;
  List<TabItem> _tabItems;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // tabitems of view
    _tabItems = <TabItem>[
      TabItem(
        view: hoge0View(),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility),
        title: 'hoge0',
        vsync: this,
      ),
      TabItem(
        view: hoge1View(),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility),
        title: 'hoge1',
        vsync: this,
      ),
      TabItem(
        view: hoge2View(),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility),
        title: 'hoge2',
        vsync: this,
      ),
      TabItem(
        view: hoge3View(),
        icon: const Icon(Icons.accessibility),
        title: 'hoge3',
        vsync: this,
      )
    ];

    for (TabItem tabItem in _tabItems) {
      tabItem.controller.addListener(_rebuild);
    }

    _tabItems[_currentIndex].controller.value = 1.0;
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    for (TabItem tabItem in _tabItems) {
      tabItem.controller.dispose();
    }
    super.dispose();
  }

  void _rebuild() {
    if (this.mounted) {
      setState(() {
        // Rebuild in order to animate views.
      });
    }
  }

  Widget _buildTransitionsStack() {
    final List<FadeTransition> transitions = <FadeTransition>[];

    for (TabItem tabItem in _tabItems) {
      transitions.add(tabItem.transition(_type, context));
    }

    // We want to have the newly animating (fading in) views on top.
    transitions.sort((FadeTransition a, FadeTransition b) {
      final Animation<double> aAnimation = a.opacity;
      final Animation<double> bAnimation = b.opacity;
      final double aValue = aAnimation.value;
      final double bValue = bAnimation.value;
      return aValue.compareTo(bValue);
    });

    return Stack(children: transitions);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final BottomNavigationBar botNavBar = BottomNavigationBar(
      items: _tabItems.map((TabItem tabItem) => tabItem.item).toList(),
      currentIndex: _currentIndex,
      type: _type,
      onTap: (int index) {
        setState(() {
          var currentView = _tabItems[_currentIndex];
          currentView.controller.reverse();
          _currentIndex = index;
          currentView = _tabItems[_currentIndex];
          currentView.controller.forward();
        });
      },
    );
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(_tabItems[_currentIndex]._title),
        actions: actions,
      ),
      body: Center(child: _buildTransitionsStack()),
      bottomNavigationBar: botNavBar,
    );
  }
}
```

Well, here I rewrite a part of the build method.
I placed a button on AppBar when index: 1 and wanted to tap and call the method of the view instance being displayed.

```
var actions = <Widget>[];
if (_currentIndex == 1) {
  var editButton = FlatButton(
      child: Text('Edit'),
      onPressed: () {
        // I want to  call hoge1View method...
      });
  actions.add(editButton);
}
return Scaffold(
  appBar: AppBar(
    title: Text(_tabItems[_currentIndex]._title),
    actions: actions,
  ),
  body: Center(child: _buildTransitionsStack()),
  bottomNavigationBar: botNavBar,
);
```

The implementation of Hoge1View is as follows.
I want to call showEditButtonDialog () when I tap the editButton.

```
class Hoge1View extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _Hoge1ViewState createState() => _Hoge1ViewState();
}

class _Hoge1ViewState extends State<DiaryView> {

  Future showEditButtonDialog() async {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (BuildContext context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: Text('test'),
            content: SingleChildScrollView(
              child: ListBody(
                children: <Widget>[Text('test message')],
              ),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('action1'),
                onPressed: () {
                  print('pressed');
                },
              )
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  @override

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return ListView(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(),
        Container(),
        Container(),
      ]
    );
  }
}
```

I do not know how to get Hoge1View instances currently displayed on onPress.